# Why it is giving Index Out Of Range Exception if i don't pre calculate value?

Tags: c#

i was trying to solve problem related to prefix sum.
In which array is given

```
var nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

and we have to find Sum of each elements in range  a, b inclusive

function is giving System.IndexOutOfRangeException

I Tried to solve this ways.

```
int[] pre;
NumArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });

Console.WriteLine(SumRanges(0,2));
Console.WriteLine(SumRange(0,2));
void NumArray(int[] nums)
{
    pre = new int[nums.Length];
    pre[0] = nums[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        pre[i] += pre[i - 1] + nums[i];
    }
}
int SumRange(int left, int right)
{
    return pre[right] - left >= 1 ? pre[left - 1] : 0;
}
int SumRanges(int left, int right)
{
    int l = left >= 1 ? pre[left - 1] : 0;
    return pre[right] - l;
}
```

My Question is Why below function is giving System.IndexOutOfRangeException

```
int SumRange(int left, int right)
{
    return pre[right] - left >= 1 ? pre[left - 1] : 0;
}
```

but below equation won't give System.IndexOutOfRangeException

```
int SumRanges(int left, int right)
{
    int l = left >= 1 ? pre[left - 1] : 0;
    return pre[right] - l;
}
```

i just only stored in variable, i am not getting why it is?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, those two method's logics are different I guess you think they are same

For this one

```
pre[right] - left >= 1 ? pre[left - 1] : 0;
```

the execution sequence is like this

```
(pre[right] - left >= 1) ? pre[left - 1] : 0;
```

It will compute the result of `(pre[right] - left >= 1)` first then execute others logic and you can change it to

```
return pre[right] - (left >= 1 ? pre[left - 1] : 0);
```

then they will be same

Answer (score 2):

With the call `SumRange(0,2)` the argument `left` will be `0`.

And if `pre[right] - left >= 1` is true then you use `pre[left - 1]`.

So if the condition is true then you use `pre[-1]`.

---

With `left >= 1 ? pre[left - 1] : 0;` you first check to make sure that `left` is larger than `0`, so `pre[left - 1]` will not use a negative index.